# Commission vs Guarantee

Tags: eu, netherlands, accommodation

First of all, sorry for the silly question, I came from a third world country, undeveloped country, so we don't have all this. (Not just for this question, but for the other questions that I am planing to ask)

I am renting an apartment because I got a job contract, and I can see online there are two main words:

Commission and Guarantee

I read and I got the following:

Commission is what I should pay to the real estate because it helps me to fine the accommodation

Guarantee is what I pay to the owner of the accommodation so if I destroy the accommodation, but when the contract finishes, if I haven't destroyed the apartment, he will give me the guaranettee back, right? (Sometime I see Deposit, which I think is the same concept as Guarantee, right?)

Is it normal they are asking me for the cost of one month as a commission?

Comment: That sort of thing varies a lot between countries, and on the rental period. What country, and how long are you renting the apartment for?

Comment: Hello Gagravarr, The country is the Netherlands, I don't have a limit on the period, if i like the accommodation, i will take it for one year, but for now i am thinking of 1 month so when i go there i check if it is okay i continue, if not i search for other accommodation

Comment: @NoblezaOcampo One year is typically a *minimum*. You would have much fewer options if you don't want to commit for one year.

Comment: Hello Gala, yes I need it for one year. You are right, all is for one year and that is fine by me.

Comment: *there are two main words*. Where? Please quote specific texts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One month rent as a fee (*vergoeding*, *bemiddelingskosten* or *huurkosten*) for a place advertised by an agency is pretty standard (can be a lower set fee for cheap accommodation, I don't recall seeing more). Another model is for the landlord or landlady to pay for the agency fee, in which case the tenant does not have to pay anything. Yet, another model is to pay an agency some pre-defined fee upfront and have them look for unlisted places for you (not sure how common this really is but many agencies offer it).

*Borgsom* (the usual translation is "deposit", I have never heard "guarantee" but I suppose it might be the same) is indeed a sum of money you give to the landlord or landlady to cover damages to the property *or rent arrears*. You should get this money back at the end of the contract, if you make sure to end it following the procedure laid out in the contract (probably by certified mail, with one month notice). Here again, one month rent is standard but if you have a low income (compared to the rent) or a temporary job, you might be required to pay more (or, alternatively, to find a guarantor living in the Netherlands but that might be difficult for an expat).

Some agencies will also ask you for some form of registration fee (before letting you even see properties) or a prepayment to confirm your interest in a property (at that point, you might still be refused by the landlord or landlady and get that money back but you cannot walk out without losing it). If you do get the property you were interested in, such a prepayment would be counted towards the deposit and agency fees and you would only have to pay the difference before moving in.

Finally, note that unless it's a vacation rental, you will rarely find anybody willing to rent you their property for one month, certainly through an agency (if you are introduced to the landlord by the current tenant or you are subrenting, it might be possible but would still seem rather uncommon). All rental contracts I have ever seen in this country specify a one-year minimum rental period. It's only after the end of the first year that you can step out of the contract with one month notice (typically).